# using for loops in C# for iterating through the master data

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to suggestion on the best practices in coding for a real scenario.
The scenario is this:
I have a list of 100 items.

```
public CustomObject 
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

List<CustomObject> lstObj = new List<CustomObject>();
```

lstobj can have sample values such as

> A,1 B,2  C,3  C,4  C,5 etc

Now, I have a tabular data as follows:

> ```
>       Low  High
> A     10   100
> Z     89   100
> ```

while looping through the list, I need to check against this data, and if suppose A value is more than 100 I need to put it to some xml file.

Now, my approach is

a) I will be putting this master data into a list formatfor eg:

```
public class CheckValues
{  
    public string name { get;set;}
    public int lowerlimit { get;set;}  
    public int upperlimit {get;set;} 
}
```

and populating the list with the data like

> ```
>     Low  High
> A   10   100
> Z   89   100
> ```

b) using a foreach loop , I will be looping the lstobj items and within this each iteration , I would be once again iterating the list to check if the item exists and if it exists whats the value (max or min)

Basically I am using the two forloops. Is it approach acceptable or is there any best practices/suggestions to improve the practice advisable on this?

Comment: Your approach sounds perfect. Just show your code. Probably there are some things to improve.

Comment: This approach looks acceptable of course, it may be just inefficient. Is your question about correctness, code clarity, or efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

If the number of entries in each list is small, your solution may be an acceptable solution, but if either of them is large, this is one of the worst ways to do it. A list means linear lookup (`n*m`). If you use some other container or if you sort first, you can achieve far better (`n*1`) performance.

I would recommend removing `name`:

```
public class CheckValues
{  
  public int lowerlimit {get;set;}
  public int upperlimit {get;set;} 
}
```

Then use `Dictionary<string, CheckValues>` to look up the limits

```
Dictionary<string, CheckValues> limits /* = ... */;
foreach(var item in data) // Just one foreach
{
    var limit = limits[item]; // Looking up the limit is O(1) instead of O(n)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can use LINQ

```
List<CustomObject> lstObj = new List<CustomObject>(){ new CustomObject(){ id = 1, name = "name1" }, new CustomObject() { id  = 2, name = "name2" } };
```

then you can select the highest value

```
CustomObject highestvalue = lstObj.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

or the lowest value

```
CustomObject lowestvalue = lstObj.OrderBy(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

you can also find data ids that's greater than 100

```
var objgreaterthan100 = lstObj.FindAll(x => x.id > 100);
```

then you can iterate to your objgreaterthan100 then put in XML.

```
foreach (var CustomObject in objgreaterthan100)
            {
                //your code for saving in xml
            }
```